# Matplotlib animate orbit path

Tags: python, matplotlib, orbit

So I'm trying to make a model of the retrograde motion of Mars.
First task is to make a model of mars and earth orbiting the sun.
Then there's a separate window of the view or Mars from Earth but I'll tackle that when I do.

So here I'm just trying to make a particle (Earth) follow a circle equation, in the example I try a parabola but it follows basically a straight line path and not a curve at all.

Have I missed something?

```
#imports
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np

#style choices
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [16.4, 10.8]


def _update_plot(i, fig, scat):
    scat.set_offsets(([i, (((i)^2)-(11*i)+400)], [50, i]))
    print('Frames: %d' %i)

    return scat





fig = plt.figure()

x = [0]
y = [0]

ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.grid(True, linestyle = '-', color = '0.50')
ax.set_xlim([-400, 800])
ax.set_ylim([-400, 800])

scat = plt.scatter(x, y, c = x)
scat.set_alpha(0.5)

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, _update_plot, fargs = (fig, scat),
                                frames = 200, interval = 300)

plt.show()
```

Comment: I don't think `(i)^2` is valid python. Don't you get any error?

Comment: Just as @ImportanceOfBeingErnest says, `^` in python isn't what you think it is. In common notation, you're looking for `i**2` instead of `(i)^2`. `^` actually performs a binary XOR operation so it won't throw any errors, but I assume it's neither the operation you actually want.

Comment: Oh yes, because `i` is always an integer it will actually "work" and give you the XOR.

Comment: Cheers guys making progress now